# Caching solution for Unique IDs

Tags: caching, unique-id

We want to build a distributed cache of Unique IDs to be used in an application to identify each transaction. UNIQUE ID is generated using some custom logic(say DATE +some random number) in java code.

The application runs in 8 application servers(Load balanced). Once a UNIQUE ID is consumed by the application, cache needs to be updated with the previously consumed value. So cache object update should be done in a multi threaded environment.

Is it better to keep local cache in each application server(Unique ID generation sequence specific to each Node). But that would not guarantee transaction ID sequence in the application.

We have been looking options of hazlecast, geode, ignite etc., to build distributed cache(peer to peer cache).But which one would work well when there is cache updation in multithreaded environment.

Which caching solution/model would best fit this problem.

Comment: You either have an authoritative central cache or you live with eventual consistency in a distributed one.  There really isn't any other choice.  Is your cache just to prevent collisions?  In that case, just use UUIDs and be done with it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

Comment: Chuck Adams - Yes to prevent collisions as well as to maintain sequence of transaction IDs.

Answer (score 0):

## No need for cache

You do not need a caching solution for your problem.

You can generate universally-unique identifiers without any need to coordinate between your systems.

### UUID

A proper solution has already been invented, standardized, implemented, and widely adopted: [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)

A Version 1 UUID represents a point in space and time, taking the current moment along with the [MAC address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) of the machine, and adds an arbitrary number that increments when the host’s clock is reset and Increments when the UUID generator restarts.

All this data is represented in a 128-bit value, with a specification for which bits represent which pieces of data. A canonical format for textual display to humans uses hexadecimal characters punctuated by hyphens.

Example:

> 1154cf8a-6f7b-11ea-bc55-0242ac130003

You asked for:

> custom logic(say DATE +some random number)

As mentioned above, some versions of UUID contain just that, a date-time plus an arbitrary number plus other info. It sounds like your team is unwisely reinventing the wheel.

UUIDs are used extensively through the IT industry. You will find them in your email headers to identify each message. You will find them as transaction IDs. You will find them as object IDs.

UUID generator implementations are built into nearly all operating systems (macOS, Linux, BSD, Windows, etc.). Libraries are publicly available, such as [OSSP uuid](http://www.ossp.org/pkg/lib/uuid/). The more powerful databases such as Postgres support UUID as a native data type for efficient storage and ease-of-use. Some software platforms such as Java include a data type for UUID and a generator implementation.

The purpose to UUIDs is that various software systems can generate UUID values on their own, on the fly, with no need for a central authority, no need for a distributed cache, and no need to coordinate with other systems.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But our requirement is to generate unique IDs based on our custom logic in our standard format. So we cannot use UUIDs. In this scenario, can you suggest the best approach?